# getting "getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection" warn message

Tags: android

Here is a code snippet from DeviceAdminReceiver subclass implemented by me:-

```
public void onDisabled(Context context, Intent intent) 
{
    super.onDisabled(context, intent);

    AntiTheftApplicationContext.setApplicationContext(
        context.getApplicationContext());

    final Context applicationContext =  AntiTheftApplicationContext.
        getApplicationContext();

    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() 
    {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            applicationContext.stopService(new Intent(applicationContext,    AuthenticationWakeupCallReceiver.class));

            applicationContext.startService(new Intent(applicationContext, AuthenticationWakeupCallReceiver.class));

        }
    });

    thread.start();

    while(AntiTheftUtil.isMyServiceRunning(
           AuthenticationWakeupCallReceiver.class.getName()))
    {
        try 
        {
            Thread.sleep(20000);
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
}
```

AuthenticationWakeupCallReceiver starts another activity i.e PostStartupAuthenticationActivity :-

```
if(!PostStartupAuthenticationActivity.isActivityRunning())
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(context,XYZ.class);

    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

XYZ activity contains an EditText which is defined as follows in layout file :-

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/re_enter_authentication_code"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="enter authentication code"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:singleLine="true" />
```

Handling for EditText is done as follows in my code:-

```
final EditText dataEnteredEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.re_enter_authentication_code);

TextWatcher watcher = new TextWatcher() 
{
    int countAttempts = 0;

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence enteredText, int start, int before, int count) 
    {
        String value = enteredText.toString();

        if(value.length() >= authenticationCode.length() &&       !value.equals(authenticationCode))
        {
            dataEnteredEditText.setError("Invalid Code!!!");

            dataEnteredEditText.setText(AntiTheftConstants.EMPTY_STRING);

            countAttempts++;

            if(countAttempts == 3)
            {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();

                editor.putBoolean(AntiTheftConstants.USER_AUTHENTICATION_STATUS, false);

                editor.commit();            

                startProcessForAuthenticationFailure();

                finish();
//          }
        }
        else if(value.equals(authenticationCode))
        {
            mIsCorrectPasswordEntered = true;

            stopService(new Intent(AntiTheftApplicationContext.getApplicationContext(), AuthenticationWakeupCallReceiver.class));

            stopService(new Intent(AntiTheftApplicationContext.getApplicationContext(), AuthenticationWakeupCallReceiver.class));

            notifySuccessfulAuthentication();
       }
    }
}
```

Problem 1 :-
But when XYZ is invoked from AuthenticationWakeupCallReceiver, EditText defined in XYZ activity stops accepting numbers. When i am entering simple letters it is being accepted but when i am entering numbers it is not getting accepted. I am getting following warning message :- "getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection".

Problem 2:-
I am looking for a better approach I want to invoke an activity from DeviceAdminReceiver subclass without starting a different thread for checking running status of my service. can i start my activity without starting a separate thread. I just want to block control flow till user is being validated. onDisabled method in DeviceAdminReceiver subclass should only complete execution when user is validated properly.